# Dynamically adding multiple values to a key in JAVA

Tags: java, android, collections

I have multiple records received as string through a query. I want to store records having the same "long" key in a collection dynamically as I parse them in a loop. Like,  insert key and value and if the key exists, it adds to the values and if not, a new key is created. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? I can do it using multiple arrays but I would prefer a cleaner way.

I cannot use a `HashMap` as I have to first store the records in an `Array` or `ArrayList` and then insert it which defeats the purpose as I have to group the lists by key first anyway. The no. of records will not more than 50 at a time.

E.g data:

```
for(i = 0; i < numRecords; i++ ) {  
    Data: 1 "A", 2 "B", 1 "C", 3 "D", 1 "E"   
}
```

I want to have a collection where inside the loop I can just add: 1 "A" and so on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Map<Long,List<String>>` may help you.

```
Map<Long,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
...
if(map.get(key)!=null){
  List<String> list = map.get(key);
  list.add(value);
}else{
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(value);
  map.put(key,list);
}
```

Comment: Why do I get this error: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
for both the new HashMap and ArrayList declaration.
I want to use only Java 1.6

Comment: then use `new  HashMap<Long,List<String>>()` as empty `<>` are not supported for java 1.6

Comment: Yes this suits my purpose ver well. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question, how efficient would be using this and then iterating again in the next segment to get the values for so few records? And can I have multiple values to one key? e.g. Long key has List<String> and List<int> as values?

Comment: Got it. Just created a class with values as members and gave the class object as List type.
Thanks a lot for your help!